# Greek characters with Alt-Gr + letter in console?

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, console, keymap, tty

I would like to implement some Greek characters into my keymap in the console (tty). I am using Arch Linux and the directory I am working in is /usr/share/kbd/i386/qwerty/uk.map, although I don't know if this is the right place to deal with the problem.

The expected result should be:

**Key pressed:** d

**Shift (or Caps Lock) pressed + letter:** D

**Alt Gr + letter:** δ

**Shift (or Caps Lock) pressed + Alt Gr + letter:** ∆

...just like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/423245), but in the console.

Any clues?

Comment: I am neither psychic or a mind reader and I don't like guessing games. What console? What operating system? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Comment: With console I mean the command console, the one you access when you type Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F7

Comment: (From the text) "I am using Arch Linux and the directory I am working in is /usr/share/kbd/i386/qwerty/uk.map"

Comment: Oh. I didn't see the question update :/ I've added the tag for you ...

Comment: No problem :) Is there anything I could add to improve it?

Comment: No idea. I don't use Linux.

Comment: Nothing I could really do to get rid of that -1 point?

Comment: LOL. I removed my downvote now you polished your question a bit :)

Comment: I'll revise it tomorrow and try to expose my problem better. I take very seriously the points given to my questions as I'd like to help the most people as possible.